# visibility issue on parent child div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am bit confused to achieve following thing
1. disable visibility of one parent div
2. but child div visibility are allowed by another code

```
<div style="background-color:#999 ; height:80px;visibility:hidden">
    <div style="background-color:#550; height:30px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#900; height:30px;visibility:visible"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbXxU/

I want to hide all the child div if parent div is not visible or any suggestion for this.

Comment: in your fiddle you dont have any children

Comment: take VisioN's advice if you add display:none; to your parent then every child will be gone!

Comment: See the difference between display: none; and visibility: hidden;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: but website is having large base code, so it calculates height of few div based on the parent height, so keeping display:none is not useful for me. I already tried this before using visibility style.

Answer (score 3):

Set `display: none` for parent element. To make it visible use `display: block`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cbXxU/1/

Comment: but website is having large base code, so it calculates height of few div based on the parent height, so keeping display:none is not useful for me. I already tried this before using visibility style.